How to get the groupingStringEnum for a StandardValueSet?
We wanted to adjust the entries available in the 'Field Usage' when editing a Custom Field on Salesforce as show in the following screenshot:

We retrieved the Definition using a package.xml and it was like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StandardValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <groupingStringEnum>FieldBusinessStatusCode</groupingStringEnum>
    <sorted>false</sorted>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Active</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Active</label>
        <groupingString>Active</groupingString>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>DeprecateCandidate</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>DeprecateCandidate</label>
        <groupingString>DeprecateCandidate</groupingString>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Hidden</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Hidden</label>
        <groupingString>Hidden</groupingString>
    </standardValue>
</StandardValueSet>

Does anyone know what the groupingStringEnum is and how can it be retrieved/adjusted?
While updating the StandardValueSet, we have to stick to the values mentioned in the previous XML.

As you know, we can add more "Field Usage" entries to the picklist by adding standardValues to the XML you present. E.g. I've just added this to the XML above:
<standardValue>
    <fullName>Cool</fullName>
    <default>false</default>
    <label>Cool</label>
    <groupingString>Active</groupingString>
</standardValue>

This gives me a new field in the picklist:

We are however not free to choose the groupingString, which must be Active, DeprecateCandidate or Hidden. The groupingStringEnum, as I understand it, is the API Name of this rather administrative set of possible values. You probably already saw the documentation regarding "Field Usage" here. If I built logic on top of this enum (e.g. by means of the Tooling API), I'd regard them as hard wired.

Hi Felix,
Thanks for your answer but that does not answer my question.
I have updated the values as stated using the existing groupingStringEnum. I wanted to know how to retrieve the groupingStringEnum values.

I've improved my answer as much as possible. If this answer is still insufficient, could you explain a little bit the use case, why you want to download a list of values that is given by Salesforce and can't be changed?

I appreciate that.
We moved from a 3 entries picklist to a 4 entries picklist with completely different values.
We did not know the possible values for groupingString neither the meeting of each entry.
We expected that there is a specific callout to get those entries and the description of each but it seems that this is not possible.
We had to use the old values without knowing the difference between each.

I see. I think Salesforce leaves it to the developers of tools (e.g. of a VSCode extension) to implement a different behaviour depending on a field that is tagged active, hidden or to be deprecated. If these three options themselves were dynamic, a tool developer had no way to react in the code to different lists of Field Usage entries.
